# DELETE Request not working , Returns status code 200

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to fire a DELETE request using HttpUrlConnection in android,I am setting the setRequestmethod as DELETE and getting a 200 as response code. The Item is not getting deleted. The async I am using is below.

```
private class DeleteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            Log.i("URL to access :", urls[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            System.out.println("ResponseCode: "+httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
            if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 204){
                Log.d(TAG,"Deleted");
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
}
```

It looks like the setRequestMethod() is not working and its taking the Request as a GET and giving me a 200 !!

I tested this in postman(a chrome extension) and it was working fine , If it was a backend issue then from postman also it should fail.
okHttp:
I was trying to make this work on okHttp also for that

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url.toString()).patch(body).build();
```

How will I make up this for delete, because delete request dosent have a body

Volly:
I've tried out the google volly library too..

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(TimerSummary.this);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, uri, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Response: "+response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Error: "+error);
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

This also returns like GET request, I am getting the item as json which was supposed to be deleted.

any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: to me it sounds like a Backend's issue

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks for the response , I tested this in postman(a chrome extension) and it was working fine, If it was a backend issue then from postman also it should fail right?

Comment: @Dev If it works with postman use a proxy like Burp or Filler and redirect your traffic thought that proxy (the one from Chrome and your Java traffic). Then compare both requests.

Comment: @Robert I dont know much about proxies .. but I'll try for sure

Comment: @Dev If it is not HTTPS you can also use Wireshark

Comment: @Robert its not .. If you dont mind , can you tell how I should test this with proxies? what am I looking for ?, Why can't I think this is a code mistake and move on to okhttp or volly?

Comment: @Robert Got the answer , The URL was wrong !!! before appending the params before "?" I forgot the "/" . That was the only issue ..Thanks for your time

Comment: I just test a restful DELETE method, and I got 204 back as response code. So you probably want to check again with your backend guys

Comment: @Blackbelt exactly ! It was actually my mistake ,but still not sure that why it is taking as GET when I miss the "/" !! anyway the problem was the "/".

Comment: no it is not /. the only conversion done is from get to post you have setDoOutput flag set to true

Comment: @Dev, you should answer your own question with what you discovered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a typo!!! I am an idiot!Both of my methods work fine ,but I am Now using Google's volly library for network related things.

I was missing a "/" before the "?" before appending  parameters with the URL